# "env\scripts\activate.bat : The module 'env' could not be loaded."

Tags: python

```
PS C:\Users\EMCEE\Downloads\iPLM\iPLM_web> env\scripts\activate.bat
env\scripts\activate.bat : The module 'env' could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module env'.
At line:1 char:1
+ env\scripts\activate.bat
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (env\scripts\activate.bat:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotAutoLoadModule
```

Answer (score 1):

For PowerShell, you should use the `activate.ps1` file instead of the `activate.bat`. Something like below should work:

```
. .\env\Scripts\activate.ps1
```